# What is the logic behind creating the boundaries of layers of a geological section?

Tags: geology, cross-section

I have data on the lithological scrapping of several wells:

The data is presented in the form -

> [depth interval from, depth interval to, layer description]

[image: wells data]

The task is to draw lines indicating the boundaries of the layers based on this data.

Here is the desired result based on my data, where the green lines mark the boundaries of the different layers:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! As it is, your post lacks some important information, so please update your question with at least the following: 1) Which software do you (want to) use; 2) What is the volume of your data? A single survey with a dozen points, or a large area with hundreds of samples? 3) What is the format of your raw data? Only Excel tables, as in the screenshot, or is there more? 4) Do you have geodata on the sample locations? In what format?  Also, please take the [tour] to see how GIS.SE works, and how to write good posts.

Comment: The lines represent boundaries between layers, and it is not clear how the layers are defined. I'm guessing the old pencil and paper would be fastest.

Comment: @crafter6029, I use the python programming language to automate design in Autocad. My dataset is an ecxel table. The size of the data depends on the number of wells and layers in them. usually 10-20 wells. The data format is a list in python in the format:

`
boreholes = [
    [
        [0, 4, 'soil'],
        [4, 8, 'clay'],
        [8, 12, 'graviy-clay'],
        [12, 20, 'graviy-sand'],
        [20, 24, 'basalts']
    ]
]
`
etc.

Regarding geodata - I have the coordinates of the wells from which I made a geological profile of the area

Comment: @LeighBettenay, pencil and paper are easier, but very slow.

The logic for defining layers is simple. We, for example, see that there is a 'clay' layer in the first well, but not in the others, which means we lead to the end of the previous 'soil' layer. Also with 'graviy-clay', this layer is also only in the first well, and we can clearly see how it is displayed. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Having drawn geological sections for 50 years I think I understand them. Let's agree to differ on whether slow is good. I think sSlow is good for drawing cross sections because it promotes geological thought and improves understanding.

Comment: @LeighBettenay, You don’t understand - I’m creating a program to automate the construction of geological sections. This will speed up the work of geologists, and your favorite industry will develop faster.

Comment: I think I do. There are hundreds of programs to do this: think Micromine (which I had some early involvement with), Surpac (which I used 40 years ago), Datamine (used on thousands on minesites), Surfer, Leapfrog etc. etc. Re-invent the wheel if you wish, but in the end all of them come down to how well you can geocode your drillhole data.